# Load a HTML page within another HTML page

Tags: html

I need to display or load a HTML page within another HTML page on a button click.I need this in a popup with the main html page as the background.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you want the user to click a button on the first HTML page, which pops up a second HTML page with the content of the first HTML page as the background of the 2nd HTML page. Is that correct?

Comment: When I click a button in first page,it should open a popup in the same page and the second HTML page should be loaded in the popup.Is there any popup other than the windows popup?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`iframe` is the tag which you can use for call other html pages into your web page

```
<iframe
    src="http://www.google.co.in"
    name="targetframe"
    allowTransparency="true"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="0"
>
</iframe>
```

Comment: how should I use this iframe? where can i click?

Comment: is this still the accepted answer? how does it compare to html5 <object>

Answer (score 12):

You can use jQuery

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#divId").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="divId" style="display:none;"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

on click event you can make it display block .

Comment: Doing this will cause the guest page to inherit the CSS style of the host page.

Answer (score 9):

Load a page within a page using an iframe. The following should serve as a good starting point.

```
<body>
  <div>
    <iframe src="page1.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div>
    <a href="page2.html" target="targetframe">Link to Page 2</a><br />
    <a href="page3.html" target="targetframe">Link to Page 3</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```js
function jsredir() {
  window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="jsredir()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are asking is not popup but lightbox. For this, the trick is to display a semitransparent layer behind (called overlay) and that required div above it.

Hope you are familiar basic javascript. Use the following code. With javascript, change display:block to/from display:none to show/hide popup.

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5); overflow: hidden; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 1000; display:block;">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 600px; position: static; margin: 20px auto; padding: 20px 30px 0px; top: 110px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1001; box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);">
        <iframe src="otherpage.html" width="400px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">Open popup</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

In **2022**

```
<div id="display" style="width: 100%;float: left;"></div>

<script>
  function load_anotherpage() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
      '<embed type="text/html" src="https://libcon.in/" width="100%" height="800" >';
  }

  load_anotherpage();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

you just need load jquery and fancybox.css and fancybox.js :

```
<!-- Add jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

and add  js code in your page:

```
$("youBtnSelector").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        href : 'you html path',
        type : 'iframe',
        padding : 5
    });
})
```

It is easy to do

Comment: Can I add some of my own JS? Like show extra details on hover...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=200,height=200');">Open</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a popup in the page, that is **not** a new browser window, then I would take a look at the various "LightBox" implementations in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

iframe is great for what it does, but it isn't a popup. I use it on some of my pages so that the browser only has to load the new content which makes it faster loading and preserves bandwidth.

With a popup that loads on top of the current window, this is the true purpose of a popup, to show content over the page you're on without unloading the page you're on. iFrame is used to preserve the main page while displaying content within a window. the old method of having a default page with < *editable content > is somewhat outmoded.
Others have provided the code I will add that using -onclick- function with a -popup- wither transparency or not. I would go with not!

Hope this clears things up.