# I want to load an external html in to my file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load an external file into my file. the external file present another server and my file present in another server.

If i use this `$("#content").load("content.html");` that is works fine the the both file in same server  but my files are having different server

Example:

my file present in my local server

inside index.html there is div having div id "content"

and menu.html file present in http://phpraddyx.com/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#content").load("menu.html");

    });
```

Comment: try `$("#content").load("http://phpraddyx.com/menu.html");`

Comment: `the external file present another server and my file present in another server` can't be done. `Cross origin issue`

Comment: also i have tried this way
`$("#content").load("http://phpraddyx.com/menu.html");`

not working

Comment: Without additional server-side technologies such as PHP, ASP, Ruby, Node.js, or Java, you cannot load most content cross-domain due to security concerns. There are a few options, such as iFrames in HTML, but these have their limits too.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032664/load-a-html-page-within-another-html-page)

Comment: if you are going to use php, try Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net, and convert the result as string so you can use it in html.

Answer (score -1):

Load a local .php file into your container which itself is getting and returning the content if the external source (this course assumes that PHP is installed)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a proxy page on you local server, e.g.

```
proxy.cgi?url='.....'
```

And use this server cgi page to fetch the url and return the content.

Answer (score -1):

If this is only for designing, use iframe instead. (e.g. loading head menu links, etc.)
<iframe src="http://phpraddyx.com/" width="#" height="#">

Or since the code will work in the same server, save the Java file on that server and load it on HTML file stored in other server:
<script src="http://phpraddyx.com/menu.js"></script>